# Restore Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to the default settings (No concern for any data or files on hard drives)

Tags: 16.04, reinstall

I started using Linux Ubuntu two weeks ago. Now, after I have installed **A LOT** of junk on it, I wish to restore it to default settings.

To further clarify. I want to reinstall Ubuntu 16.04.LTS, but I was wondering is there any other way to do it **(A quicker way**) besides using USB or CD . Like some commands for terminal which would result in the same thing??

Thanks.

Comment: I highly doubt there is a command to do to that. I clean install takes > 30 min so I would recommend just doing that